# Java command prompt loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I have this simple code that works like a small command prompt. User is asked to enter a command and is displayed a message according to what he entered. I just want to make it loop so that the user is asked to enter a command again and again and again until he types 'exit'. How do I do that?
Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner command = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter command: ");

    String text = command.nextLine();

        switch(text){

        case "start":
            System.out.println("Machine started!");
            break;

        case "stop":
            System.out.println("Machine stopped.");
            break;

        case "exit":
            System.out.println("Application Closed");
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Command not recognized!");
            break;
        }

    command.close();
}
```

Thank you

Comment: while ( not condition met ){

/* your code */ 
reset value to test
}

Comment: Try to use chain if-else and use text.equals("xxxxxx") for the condition.

Comment: @farukdgn: why would he do that?

Comment: @Stultuske http://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/3025112

Comment: @farukdgn: you are testing for the wrong value. "xxxxxxxx" and "exit" will never be equal. I was, however, referring to your if-else proposal.

Comment: @Stultuske Do you want me to write it again and again for every single condition? "xxxxxx" means "start", "stop" or "exit.

Comment: @farukdgn: again: I was actually referring to your if-else proposal, not your recommendation to use equals or equalsIgnoreCase. Considering the OP has some issues with writing loops, assuming he's not a coding guru and is capable of making mistakes, is not that far fetched, though.

Comment: @Stultuske Sorry for misunderstanding. I don't know any way to do it with switch-case, so I recommended if-else. Is there any way?

Comment: @farukdgn: the way the OP implemented it works just fine (if you are using Java 7 or above, that is)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner command = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter command: ");
    boolean running = true;

    while(running){

        switch(command.nextLine()){

        case "start":
            System.out.println("Machine started!");
            break;

        case "stop":
            System.out.println("Machine stopped.");
            break;

        case "exit":
            System.out.println("Application Closed");
            running = false;
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Command not recognized!");
            break;
        }
    }
    command.close();
}
```

Comment: Constantly re-declaring text? Why not just once?

Comment: @Stultuske How's that bad? Keeping references within their own scope.

Comment: @Bubletan: it was more a question than a remark. considering the scope here:
String text = "";
while ( .... ){ /* code */ }
Yes, limiting to the scope is not bad, but re-creating the instance variable each time, there are those who don't like to see that either.

Comment: @Stultuske Yah, best way would be just `switch (command.nextLine())`.

Answer (score 3):

You can put it in a while loop like this:

```
String text = "";

while(!text.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
{
    System.out.println("Enter command: ");

    text = command.nextLine();

        switch(text){

        case "start":
            System.out.println("Machine started!");
            break;

        case "stop":
            System.out.println("Machine stopped.");
            break;

        case "exit":
            System.out.println("Application Closed");
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Command not recognized!");
            break;
        }
}
```

Just let the condition for your while loop be while text <> "exit".

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? I prefer do-while for this type of situation because you probably want to give at least one command.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean running = true;

    Scanner command = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter command: ");
        String text = command.nextLine();
        switch(text){
            case "start":
                System.out.println("Machine started!");
                break;
            case "stop":
                System.out.println("Machine stopped.");
                running = false;  //here?
                break;
            case "exit":
                System.out.println("Application Closed");
                running = false; //..or here?
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Command not recognized!");
                break;
        }
    } while(running);
    command.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

while loop is missing in the initial example:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    while (true) {
        String command = br.readLine().toLowerCase();

        switch (command) {
            case "exit": {
                // exit here
            } break;

            default: {
                // unrecognised command
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You misspelled `siwtch`. Also, you're never leaving the while-loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a switch, easiest way would probably be a simple infinite while-loop with a label. When the input matches `"exit"`, we just break the loop.

```
loop:
while (true) {
    String text = command.nextLine();
    switch (text) {
    // ...
    case "exit":
        break loop;
    }
}
```